# OpenShift deploying local application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, openshift

I followed both of their guides:

1. Setting up RHC gem [**Here**](https://www.openshift.com/get-started#cli)
2. Setting up private/public key and Putty [**Here**](https://www.openshift.com/developers/remote-access#keys)

However I cannot deploy my rails application to the server. Following their tutorial I have to deploy it using Git. No problem here so I added my project directory `git add .` made a commit `git commit -a -m "OS Deploy"` and then `Git push` however this wont work as I don't know where to find the address of my OpenShift application.

So I have no idea how to transfer code from local machine to OpenShift application.

How do I go about deploying my application. Also would it be possible to simply pull the code from my git repo ?

I found my app address: `ssh://***094@corporation -eveonline.rhcloud.com/~/git/corporation.git/`

However when I try to push my local application to OpenShift i get:

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 420, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (202/202), done.
remote: Total 420 (delta 186), reused 420 (delta 186)
Receiving objects: 100% (420/420), 140.16 KiB | 138 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (186/186), done.
From ssh://corporation-eveonline.rhcloud.com/~/git/corporation
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging script/rails
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in script/rails
Auto-merging config/routes.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/routes.rb
Auto-merging config/initializers/session_store.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/initializers/session_store.rb
Auto-merging config/initializers/secret_token.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/initializers/secret_token.rb
Auto-merging config/environments/test.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/environments/test.rb
Auto-merging config/environments/production.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/environments/production.rb
Auto-merging config/environments/development.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/environments/development.rb
Auto-merging config/environment.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/environment.rb
Auto-merging config/database.yml
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/database.yml
Auto-merging config/application.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config/application.rb
Auto-merging config.ru
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in config.ru
Auto-merging app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
Auto-merging app/controllers/application_controller.rb
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Auto-merging app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
Auto-merging Rakefile
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Rakefile
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in README.md
Auto-merging Gemfile.lock
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Gemfile.lock
Auto-merging Gemfile
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Gemfile
Auto-merging .gitignore
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .gitignore
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

So I tried push to my app address again and did not get that error however I did get:
https://gist.github.com/nered/82d7ca1fa334617210c1 error

Comment: You can see my post here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727788/deploying-ruby-on-rails-is-there-a-good-alternative-for-heroku

Comment: You can see my post here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727788/deploying-ruby-on-rails-is-there-a-good-alternative-for-heroku

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the resources found in the developer center for Ruby? https://www.openshift.com/developers/ruby

There's a quickstart (https://github.com/openshift/rails-example) that you can try before deploying your own code, just to get familiar with deploying rails apps.  After the quickstart, you can check out the blogs to see if they help as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is [Sync new git repo with your own existing git repo](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1006-sync-new-git-repo-with-your-own-existing-git-repo).